# "validate-number-range" validation not working in Adminhtml form created using Ui Component

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, adminform

I am trying to implement the **validate-number-range** but it is not working.

Please find the implementation below

```
    <field name="custom_sequence" sortOrder="40" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <required>true</required>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="validate-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="validate-number-range" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="number-range-1-50" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>number</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Custom Sequence</label>
                <dataScope>custom_sequence</dataScope>
                <componentType>field</componentType>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validate-number-range` rule must have the type string and should have the range as its value, e. g. `<rule name="validate-number-range" xsi:type="string">1-50</rule>`.

Example snippet:

```xml
<validation>
    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
    <rule name="validate-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
    <rule name="validate-number-range" xsi:type="string">1.00-50.00</rule>
</validation>
```

Comment: thanks you Pascal Zarrad, You are my saviour.